# C# using Process.Start for exe in a sub folder launches in same folder as launching exe

Tags: c#, directory, process.start

I'm having issues with a self written application updater and when I launch the main program (in a sub folder) from the updater using Process.Start:

```
Folder Structure:
\Updater\
\Updater\Updater Workspace\
\Updater\Application\
```

The updater launches checks the version of the application in `\Updater\Application\` compares it to the latest version (updates if necessary) and launches `application.exe` in `\Updater\Application\`

The application.exe on launch does a check for a `user.prefs` file and if its not found automatically creates this in `\Updater\` instead of `\Updater\Application\`

Why wold process.start spawn the process in the same directory as the launching exe?

Comment: You would have to show us some code...

Comment: Have you set `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to where you actually want it to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why wold process.start spawn the process in the same directory as the
>   launching exe?

Unless you specified another directory, the working directory of the spawn process inherits from the parent process.

You can change this behavior by specifying a `ProcessStartInfo` parameter to `Process.Start`.

See [`Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)